# MongoDb gets slow when large amount of data already installed?

Tags: mongodb

I am a new user of mongodb, I m currently doing a stress test, 100thousands data per 5s are inserting with 10 threads and we have already stored x00million of data. The db is getting gravely slow. Although when I restart the computer it get faster for a while, it drops down again after a short period of time. why is that? Can I do something to avoid?

Answer (score 0):

Please share more information. What queries do you have? Please don't take this as a complete answer because this is just a suggestion. I can not add comments unfortunately. You may try this;

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/repairDatabase/

Comment: Well I need a specific answer like excectly my situation. db data insertion gets slow when i already inserted a huge amount of data around x00million of data. im inserting 100thousds data per 5s.